# How do I determine if mining Ether is going to be a viable (profitable) endeavor?

Tags: mining, solo-mining

I'm new to Ethereum and mining. I would like to start mining for Ether and have been following threads and articles on the AMD 290's GPU capabilities and would probably want to lean towards this adapter.

How can I determine if starting to mine (solo) today makes financial sense? What factors do I need to take into account?

edit: for hardware, contemplating an i7 4th/6th gen or xeon 5th gen, probably around $1k range. for gpu i am planning up to 3 290's. as for electricity, it averages around $.13/kwh where i am.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions [instead of combining](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) your questions into one. [That way](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: It depends how much you spent for your hardware, how expensive is your electricity and how much r9 290 cards you want to run. Without those 3 information, I can't tell.

Comment: I've nominated it to be reopened but edited it so that the question is more likely to yield useful answers and information for others in the community. If you would like someone to help you with specifics of *your* case, I recommend heading over to https://www.reddit.com/r/ethermining and posting the cost of hardware, electricity, hardware specs, etc.

Comment: Some calculations and other considerations available at [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether) and [What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether/2722#2722).