# Mining difficulty compared to bitcoin

Tags: mining

What is current payout of ether mining compared by bitcoin mining in terms of usd per unit of electricity/time?
Can hardware designed for bitcoin can be used for ether with same efficiency?

I ask this in particular due to bitcoin halfing of 25 USD per block which as I understand is due to happen in nearest future to estimate if significant mining resources will be moved from bitcoin to ether mining.

Comment: Have you heard of [minerall.io](https://minerall.io/) ? I wanted to hear some recs before going there

Answer (score 2):

Hardware designed for bitcoin can't be used for Ethereum due it's "memory hardness" property, created by the [DAG](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-DAG). This is intended, as ASICS are seen as a centralization force in Bitcoin.
Mining Ethereum currently is not profitable if you have to buy new equipment, many persons including me think. There are some mining calculators on the interwebs you can try out.

Comment: Thank you. I have GT8800 video with 512Mb memory. I want to try. After how many hours/days can I expect to gain some? Maybe you may recommend a pool? I want to try Etherium, but don't want to buy ether with fiat currency.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov you need at least 3Go of VRAM for the dag to be loaded on the card.

Answer (score 1):

> What is current payout of ether mining compared by bitcoin mining in
>   terms of usd per unit of electricity/time?

See these previous threads:

- [How do I determine if mining Ether is going to be a viable (profitable) endeavor?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3879/how-do-i-determine-if-mining-ether-is-going-to-be-a-viable-profitable-endeavor)
- [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether)

> Can hardware designed for bitcoin can be used for ether with same
>   efficiency?

Not really. See Roland's answer.

> I ask this in particular due to bitcoin halfing of 25 USD per block
>   which as I understand is due to happen in nearest future to estimate...

The Bitcoin halving happened 2 days ago (as of the time of your post). At the time of this answer, the price is 5% lower than before the halving (which is neither here nor there, given its volatility).

> ...if significant mining resources will be moved from bitcoin to ether
>   mining.

No. See Roland's answer.