# How may I buy and register a Ethereum node for mining?

Tags: mining, nodes

I would like to provide a Ethereum node in the State of Florida in the USA.
How many Ethereum nodes are already on-line in Florida?
How do I go about buying and registering a new Ethereum node?

Comment: What sort of node? Full or also mining? What for? How do you think we care of the location of the node? Why do you think a node is different than a standard computer? Why do you want a node ? So many questions you need to answer before asking how to build a node...

Comment: [Ethernodes](http://ethernodes.org/network/1) would suggest there's a few there already...

Comment: I am interested in an Ethereum node that would be dedicated to mining. As such I assume there is a specific operating system (Ubuntu?) and Ethereum version required for mining. I assume I could use a DELL PowerEdge T630 Tower Server for the hardware. Iplan to connect to AT&T's fiber network.

Comment: See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to buy or register an Ethereum node.  You can simply download one of the clients such as [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) and run it on a computer connected to the network.

Ethereum nodes will automatically connect to other nodes and synchronize a copy of the Ethereum blockchain, so there's no formal registration needed.

If you want to stand up a mining node, that will require some advanced setup.  Either way, I'd highly recommend you read through [Ethereum's documentation](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/#) before you get started.