# Can you mine with 2GB cards or less? Thinking about the DAG issues

Tags: mining-pools, hardware, rig

So I'm really new to mining and I tried setting up a Claymore miner on a rig with a 2GB card, it gave me a error saying something that the DAG wasnt enough and then I looked it up on google and I only found articles saying that you cant mine with 2GB cards anymore or less because there is no miner that supports it..

I wanted to setup a rig with a bunch of cheap cards everywhere from 1-4GB
But I'm starting to reconsider it because if you cant mine with anything less than 4GB cards it wont be worth getting those cheap cards.

Can you mine with lower than 4GB cards such as 1gb 2 gb 3 gb? I know it will give you a low Mh/s just wondering if its possible.

If not, can you hook up four 1 gb hards or eight 512mb cards?

Comment: See [What is the current DAG size? When do we expect to hit GPU limits?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-is-the-current-dag-size-when-do-we-expect-to-hit-gpu-limits)

Comment: @BokkyPooBah That helped a bit, but still doesnt answer the question about me using four 1 gb cards or eight 512 mb cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum card is is 2 GB at the moment. From [What is the current DAG size? When do we expect to hit GPU limits?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/426/what-is-the-current-dag-size-when-do-we-expect-to-hit-gpu-limits), this limit may be exceeded around mid-Dec 2016, a little more than 1 month away.

Combining cards with lower RAM sizes does not work. Each card will need to have at least the minimum RAM size.

The RAM size does not make as much difference to the computation speed - your card either has enough RAM or not. The GPU computation speed is more dependent on the RAM speed, the bus speed, the GPU speed and the number of GPUs.

You may want to check out [What's the best hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether). You may also want to check out [Is CPU mining even worth the Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/is-cpu-mining-even-worth-the-ether) as this Q&A has some information on the electricity cost calculations.

**Note**: As of June 2017 it is no longer possible to mine using 2 GB cards  see this post [No longer possible to mine with 2GB Video cards](https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/comments/6gr8pt/no_longer_possible_to_mine_with_2gb_video_cards/).