# How to tell how many graphics cards a mother board can concurrently use (can each pcie 3.0 slot be used?)

Tags: mining, gpu, hardware

looking at motherboards on newegg I am filtering based on ones that have 4 or 5 pcie 3.0 slots. my 2nd criteria will be the most efficient cpu for less power consumption.

My question is if you are building a rig how can you tell if the motherboard will actually accept a graphics card in every PCIe 3.0 slot. I plan to use risers, but I have read online that just because the motherboard has 5 pcie 3.0 slots doesnt mean it will actually be able to handle 5 graphics cards for mining. Is  there any way to tell? I know this mining scenario isnt very mainstream so reviews rarely mention this. (All the Asrock mining boards seem to be sold out and those are the only ones i have seen that confirm the ability to accept a graphics card in every PCIe slot).

Sub question, can i plug a pcie 3.0 card into a pcie 2.0 slot? The rx 480 says its pcie 3.0, does that mean I cant plug it into a pcie 2.0 slot?

[What's the best Hardware for Mining Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether)

I noticed that thread and was hoping to ask a more detailed question in regards to determining if a specific motherboard is appropriate or not.

Comment: Hi there. Your question doesn't appear to specifically relate to Ethereum, so I don't think this is the forum which will provide you the best answers. I'd suggest asking at the Stack Exchange SuperUser page, which I believe also covers hardware: https://superuser.com/

Comment: good catch, I always assumed super user was about system admin tasks, didnt realized it also covered hardware. Thank you.

Comment: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2719/whats-the-best-hardware-for-mining-ether   can someone who put this on hold @RichardHorrocks explain why my question doesnt relate to ethereum yet this highly upvoted question does relate? 

Super user also closed this saying it was off topic. They suggested the bitcoin section but I am putting together hardware for ethereum. Is hardware related questions out of scope for stackexchange in general and would somewhere like toms hardware forum be better?

Comment: Hi again. The question you've linked to is specifically asking about Ethereum hardware, whereas your question doesn't really mention Ethereum at all - it's a generic mining hardware question, and really it's just about hardware (you could use the same hardware for lots of things unrelated to mining). Tom's Hardware might be a good place, or maybe https://www.reddit.com/r/EtherMining/ (but again, they might say your question is too generic).